# Delete documents less than 30 days in Marklogic Xquery

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I have a datetime field, I have to delete documents less than 30 days. How can that be acheived in xquery
like datetimefield<30 days.

Comment: What have you tried?  There are several basic XQuery functions supporting date/duration comparisons and calculations, see http://www.datypic.com/books/xquery/chapter20.html

Comment: I think its a javascript. For the days eg.30 days I dont see any command in xquery. correct me if wrong

Comment: Is the field indexed with a range index (dateTime or string)?

Comment: Your question is tagged xquery. Are you looking for a JavaScript or XQuery solution (you can execute either/both in MarkLogic).

Comment: xquery @MadsHansen

Comment: field is datetime @MadsHansen

Comment: it is not indexed @MadsHansen .

Comment: And when you say "less than 30 days" you mean documents that are less than 30 days old and have a dateTime that is within 30 days of current-dateTime()? Or do you mean with dateTime values < current-dateTime() that are more than 30 days old?

Answer (score 1):

When searching for dateTime ranges, a range-index would be the best/fastest.

With a dateTime element-range index you can do something like this:

```
let $thirtyDaysAgo := current-dateTime() - xs:dayTimeDuration("P30D")
return
  cts:search(doc(), 
    cts:and-query((
      cts:element-range-query(xs:QName("myDateTimeField"), ">", $thirtyDaysAgo),
      cts:element-range-query(xs:QName("myDateTimeField"), "<", current-dateTime())
    ))
```

If you don't have a range index, then you could search for documents that contain that field and apply a predicate filter to the search results (hopefully narrowing down the number of candidates as much as possible, maybe even looking for years and months that would be included in that date range as words within that field)

```
cts:search(doc(), 
  cts:element-query(xs:QName("myDateTimeField"), cts:true-query())
)[.//myDateTimeField[xs:dateTime(.) gt $thirtyDaysAgo and xs:dateTime(.) lt current-dateTime()]]
```

However, filtering with the predicate can be slow if there are a lot of candidates returned from the search. Using a more specific XPath to target that element instead of `//` descendant axis might also help slightly.