# Xquery in Marklogic to return datetime less than 1 month from the current date

Tags: xquery, marklogic

[Delete documents less than 30 days in Marklogic Xquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67892135/delete-documents-less-than-30-days-in-marklogic-xquery)

I was searching over the internet to find how to return documents less than 1 month old from the current date and i found the above link. Since there are no range indexes for the element i am using

```
let $currentdt := fn:current-dateTime()
let $amonthAgo := $currentdt- xs:yearMonthDuration("P1M")
cts:search(doc(), 
  cts:element-query(xs:QName("myDateTimeField"), cts:true-query())
)[.//myDateTimeField[xs:dateTime(.) eq $amonthAgo]]
```

returns nothing.

---

I have sample values such as

```
2021-05-18T06:32:34.761729-04:00
2021-05-15T06:32:34.761729-04:00
2021-03-19T06:32:34.761729-04:00
2021-06-15T06:32:34.761729-04:00
```

TIA!

Answer (score 2):

Aside from a missing `return` for the FLWOR expression, you are asking for all matches that are *exactly* one month old, because you are using `eq` in the comparison. If you want to find documents that are younger than one month, you want their date to be *after* the point in time exactly one month ago (i.e., `$amonthAgo`). You can correct and simplify the predicate to `xs:dateTime(myDateTimeField) gt $amonthAgo`. Here is a stand-alone example that works for me:

```
declare context item := document {
  <doc>
    <e id="1">
      <myDateTimeField>2021-05-18T06:32:34.761729-04:00</myDateTimeField>
    </e>
    <e id="2">
      <myDateTimeField>2021-05-15T06:32:34.761729-04:00</myDateTimeField>
    </e>
    <e id="3">
      <myDateTimeField>2021-03-19T06:32:34.761729-04:00</myDateTimeField>
    </e>
    <e id="4">
      <myDateTimeField>2021-06-15T06:32:34.761729-04:00</myDateTimeField>
    </e>
  </doc>
};
let $currentdt := fn:current-dateTime()
let $amonthAgo := $currentdt - xs:yearMonthDuration("P1M")
return //e[xs:dateTime(myDateTimeField) gt $amonthAgo]
```

Result (on 2021-06-19):

```
<e id="4">
  <myDateTimeField>2021-06-15T06:32:34.761729-04:00</myDateTimeField>
</e>
```